# Preserve order of results with async.map

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, async.js

I need to make multiple asynchronous calls, and make sure the results stay **in the same order** as the calls. How can I achieve that with the `async` library?

```
async.map(['item1', 'item2', 'item3'], function (itemName, callback){

    // Ajax GET item on server
    // ...

    // Once we have the item, return it
    callback(null, item);

}, function(error, results){

    // The results array is not necessarily sorted by order of calls
    // It can be [item2, item3, item1]

    // I want to ensure it will always be [item1, item2, item3]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The results array is not necessarily sorted by order of calls
>   It can be `[item2, item3, item1]`

Well, **no**. Why do you think so? [The docs](https://github.com/caolan/async#map) explicitly state:

> *the results array will be in the same order as the original `arr`.*

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. I still have some unordered results so I might just have overlooked a bug somewhere else.

Comment: @Atlas23250: If you'd show us your complete code, we might be able to help you with that.